# PostgreSql Select query performance issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a simple select query:

```
SELECT * FROM entities WHERE entity_type_id = 1 ORDER BY entity_id
```

Then I want to get the first 100 results, so I use this:

```
SELECT * FROM entities WHERE entity_type_id = 1 ORDER BY entity_id LIMIT 100
```

The problem is that the second query works much slower then the first one. It takes less than a second to execute the first query and more than a minute to execute the second one.

These are execution plans for the queries:

without limit:

```
Sort  (cost=26201.43..26231.42 rows=11994 width=72)
  Sort Key: entity_id
  ->  Index Scan using entity_type_id_idx on entities  (cost=0.00..24895.34 rows=11994 width=72)
        Index Cond: (entity_type_id = 1)
```

with limit:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..8134.39 rows=100 width=72)
  ->  Index Scan using xpkentities on entities  (cost=0.00..975638.85 rows=11994 width=72)
        Filter: (entity_type_id = 1)
```

I don't understand why these two plans are so different and why the performance decreases so much. How should I tweak the second query to make it work faster?

I use PostgreSql 9.2.

Comment: Is entity_id primary key or does it have any index?

Comment: entity_id is a primary key and there's an index on entity_type_id

Comment: Then you don't need order by as it is already sorted by entity_id ascending as default.

Comment: I get different results it I don't use order by.

Comment: @Kuzgun - don't be ridiculous. Nothing is sorted until you specify an "order by".

Comment: ID columns usually are sorted. Not always but usually.

Comment: @Kuzgun. No they are not. Not always, not usually, but never. The SQL standards are quite clear on what ordering result sets have by default and it is "no guaranteed order".

Comment: @RichardHuxton rows are sorted by insertion order by default. If you do not update ID column, it will remain that way. Of course there is no guaranteed order because you can always update that column. But "usually" people don't tend to update id columns. But it depends on project and user of course.

Comment: @Kuzgun - it's still no. You are quite simply incorrect about this. Any updates/deletes to the table can change the ordering on disk. In any case the order on disk is completely irrelevant to the order in a result-set. Since all we as users ever have are result-sets on-disk order is only of interest to the planner.

Comment: @RichardHuxton you are talking for any data and I agree with you on data storage is chaotic on disc. But, this one is id column, has index on it and it is a primary key, thats what I asked first. Physical data will be inserted in order of insertion date since it is associated with index for this column. Pulling data order depends on query, but this one is a simple select query.

Comment: @Kuzgun - so what? Irrelevant.

Comment: I will not answer to your argumentation anymore, it is crossing the line of helping the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want the 100 smallest entity_id's matching your condition. Now - if those were numbers 1..100 then clearly using the entity_id index is the best way to handle this - everything is pre-sorted. In fact, if the 100 you wanted were in the range 1..200 then it still makes sense. Probably 1..1000 would.

So - PostgreSQL thinks it will find lots of entity_type_id=1 values at the "start" of the table. It estimates a cost of 8134 vs 26231 to filter by type then sort. In your case it is wrong.

Now - either there is some correlation which isn't obvious (that's bad - we can't tell the planner about that at present), or we don't have up-to-date or sufficient stats.

Does an `ANALYZE entities` make any difference? You can see what values the planner knows about by reading the [planner-stats page in the manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-stats.html).